# How to perform vertical addition of column for each two rows in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table named ct_rt and there is one field ct. The data in the filed is following :

```
100
450
-20
500
300
-50
```

Now i want to get the following result :

```
100
550
530
1030
1330
1280
```

which is the addition of each row with its succeeding row. So how can I get the desired output ? I am using Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.1.0 - 64bit Production. Please help me.

Thank you. :)

Comment: Have you tried to write the query yet? Please post your query if yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done using a window function with a "cumulative sum":

```
select ct,
       sum(ct) over (order by some_column) as the_sum
from ct_rt
order by some_column;
```

You *have* to supply a column to sort the result. Rows in a relation database are ***not*** sorted and come in essentially a random order unless you specify an `order by`. The cumulative sum has the same "restriction" and therefor you have to supply an `order by` in the definition of the window function.

A good candidate for sorting this result is a timestamp column that defines when the row has been inserted (or updated). A unique, increasing id column is also a good candidate.

Comment: I am using Oracle Database 12c

Comment: @AbhilashMandaliya: the query will work with Oracle (and many other DBMS)

Answer (score 0):

Solution using a correlated subquery (you need an id field though)

```
SELECT (
    SELECT sum(ct) 
    FROM ct_rt AS sub
    WHERE sub.id <= qry.id
)
FROM ct_rt AS qry
ORDER BY qry.id
```

Edit: 
This is an alternative solution.
The solution of a_horse_with_no_name will most propably outperform this.

Comment: This is not necessary in Oracle. The solution with the window function will perform much better.

Answer (score -2):

Check this one it may help you

```
select numbers,SUM(numbers) over(order by rowid) nxtx
from txd;
```

Comment: This doesn't improve on the good answer by a_horse_with_no_name, but is rather bad, because order by rowid is arbitrary and random

Comment: but its not necessary,if its in any order then it may result to wrong answer even in the the case of some column id and if one wants the result in the same manner the data is entered than its useful...

Comment: and even i didn't saw the above answer when i posted it as i didn't refreshed my page as it was open from long time .... that answer is correct too but could lead to wrong answer when it comes to bulk data and one requires the result in the way the data is inserted .

Comment: even one can use rowid with some column id if required, to get appropriate result in the manner of data insertion –

Comment: Sorting by rowid does not sort "in the way the data is inserted".

Comment: @JeffreyKemp i think your are not practical with it,you must try it  .... by inserting some data in some table and check the order of data insertion using rowid and here i am talking of oracle or if you require then i can illustrate you

Comment: No, @Dharmesh, rowids are not guaranteed to be in any particular order. See for example http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/73884/oracle-rowid-can-we-assume-it-is-sequential-in-a-insert-only-scenario

Comment: please check this one @JeffreyKemp https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns008.htm

Comment: @Dharmesh, I'm familiar with that document. What exactly leads you to believe that it supports your idea that the values have any intrinsic order? A ROWID only encodes the *location* of the data. The location of the data can and often will change; and insertions are not always at the "end" of the storage space for the table.

Comment: you are correct @JeffreyKemp ....after making some insertion and deletion i come to conclusion that rowids are not guaranteed to be in any particular sequence..... thanks for correcting me at this point .